# List optimizes erratically

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

If I execute the below code and do not press any key on the console

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Test> list = new List<Test>(1) {new Test()};
        Console.ReadKey();
        GC.KeepAlive(list);
        var x = list[0];
        Console.WriteLine((x.ToString()));
    }
}

class Test
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Empty object";
    }
}
```

Then upon analyzing the array in windbg I see the list do not contain the test object I added. 
[image]

The element in the 0'th position is something else which i am not sure of

[image]

However if i add a string property to my Test class like so

```
class Test
{
    public string Name = "Rohit";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Empty object";
    }
}
```

Then this time windbg reveals the object

[image]
[image]

Can someone please help explain what is going on? I test the above using Visual Studio 2015 (.net 4 compatability mode) on x64 windows 7

Aside: Even though i requested for the list size to be one (for my test), i see it is going with the default size of 128. So basically the initial capacity is based on some heuristics etc?

Comment: Is this of some practical value? Or just a curiosity?

Comment: curiosity :)  just experimenting and learning windbg

Comment: Hard to see why you are poking at the Object[], the Test[] array is clearly visible in the heap dump.  That's where the `List<Test>` stores its elements.  The single Test object that's stored in the array is clearly visible as well.

Comment: @HansPassant No that is a reference http://i.imgur.com/Y0JvCNB.png

Comment: @HansPassant Just FYI, all List<T> is stored in the array of type object, the <T> type is stored as metadata some where else (read more on reified generics), so the array and list all goes to System.Object[].

Comment: Thanks for the lesson, but that's nonsense.  You are talking about ArrayList.  The generic List<T> stores its elements in a T[].  The point of generics.  Something you can easily reason out from what the debugger told you, there is no other way your program could have produced a Test[] array.

Comment: @HansPassant Just to convince you see what Test[] reveals http://i.imgur.com/8QbAjVJ.png, now look at what System.Object[] reveals http://i.imgur.com/ybJHH8G.png  http://i.imgur.com/TMiqTSq.png. Could you please write a program for your self and then use windbg and show the same? What you are mixing up is reference vs backing field, List uses array as backing field and if you iterate over it you can see that it is of type System.Object[] and not Test[].

Comment: But you also clearly have a `Test[]`. Why do you think the `object[]` is a better match?  I'm not sure what that is but try removing the `GC.KeepAlive(list);` in order to simplify.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I use object[] because i know for a fact that the backing array type is object[] (I can see my property name if i follow http://i.imgur.com/ybJHH8G.png http://i.imgur.com/TMiqTSq.png - i can't convince you more), i can see the same if i go the long winded way via Test[] but when i know it is going to be in the object[] array i directly jump to it.

Comment: No, the backing array type is `Test[]`. Why can't we convince you of that?

Comment: @HenkHolterman if the backing array type is Test[] why windbg shows system.object[], did you see the two pngs I attached to your reply?

Comment: I looked at a few, why does it also show `Test[]` ? Did you remove the keepAlive yet?

Comment: GC.KeepAlive was a typo from my previous code and has no affect. Per yours and @HansPassant suggestion the correct way is to look at Test[], so digging via Test[] and not object[] can you explain why I see the same difference i.e. When Property is not declared on Test class I see no fields http://i.imgur.com/ZzmYqXT.png vs when property is declared i can see the same field with property "Rohit" set http://i.imgur.com/WYghv2x.png. Hope this proves that Test[] uses Object as backing field?

Comment: if this does not convince you look at http://i.imgur.com/PjV2aTp.png as a proof

Comment: That's not the proof you think it is. Strings are interned, and there is some `object[]` table that holds the string _as well_, not instead of.

Comment: You asked me to use test[], I expanded as you suggested and reached the same object both via test and object array, is that not a proof, maybe I should add an int property, would that help?

Answer (score 6):

### From List to the object

From the comments I see some confusion whether a `List<T>` stores its items in an `Object[]` or `T[]`.

I compiled the program in VS 2013.4 for .NET 4.0 and I'm debugging in WinDbg 6.2.9600:

```
0:007> !dumpheap -stat
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
000007feed598130        1           24 System.Security.HostSecurityManager
000007feed597158        1           24 System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1[[System.Type, mscorlib]]
000007fe91bd40c0        1           24 ConsoleWriteLine.Test
000007feed592090        1           28 System.Char[]
000007feed5980b8        1           32 System.Security.Policy.Evidence+EvidenceLockHolder
000007feed5975e8        1           32 System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory
000007feed5974a0        1           32 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePEFileHandle
000007feed594810        1           32 System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
000007feed594780        1           32 System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
000007feed536fd8        1           40 Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native+InputRecord
000007fe91bd4150        1           40 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
000007feed591480        1           48 System.SharedStatics
000007feed5945a8        1           56 System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
000007feed5943e0        1           56 System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly
000007feed598038        1           64 System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock
000007feed597548        1           64 System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory
000007feed592610        1           64 System.Security.PermissionSet
000007feed593af0        1           72 System.RuntimeFieldInfoStub
000007feed592478        1           72 System.Security.Policy.Evidence
000007feed5913e8        3           72 System.Object
000007feeced7d10        1           80 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Security.Policy.EvidenceTypeDescriptor, mscorlib]]
000007feed591e00        1          128 System.AppDomainSetup
000007feed591310        1          160 System.ExecutionEngineException
000007feed591298        1          160 System.StackOverflowException
000007feed591220        1          160 System.OutOfMemoryException
000007feed591038        1          160 System.Exception
000007feed591540        1          216 System.AppDomain
00000000002e9e60        8          216      Free
000007feed591388        2          320 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
000007feed593920        4          492 System.Int32[]
000007feed597fd8        3          720 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Security.Policy.EvidenceTypeDescriptor, mscorlib]][]
000007feed592eb8       21         1176 System.RuntimeType
000007feed590e08       37         2786 System.String
000007feed524918        8        34808 System.Object[]
Total 112 objects
```

Compared to your output, I have no `String[]`, no `Type[]`and no `Test[]`. Instead I have 8 `Object[]`. Similar to you, I have only 1 `List<T>`. Let's find out which array it uses. The steps should be the same on your machine, but you might get `Test[]` as the result.

Step 1: dump all `List<T>`:

```
0:007> !dumpheap -mt 000007fe91bd4150
         Address               MT     Size
00000000021a2de8 000007fe91bd4150       40     

Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
000007fe91bd4150        1           40 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
Total 1 objects
```

Step 2: dump the only `List<T>` which is there:

```
0:007> !do 00000000021a2de8 
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
MethodTable: 000007fe91bd4150
EEClass:     000007feecf7ea08
Size:        40(0x28) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007feed524918  4000cd1        8      System.Object[]  0 instance 00000000021a2e10 _items
000007feed593980  4000cd2       18         System.Int32  1 instance                1 _size
000007feed593980  4000cd3       1c         System.Int32  1 instance                1 _version
000007feed5913e8  4000cd4       10        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _syncRoot
000007feed524918  4000cd5        8      System.Object[]  0   static  <no information>
```

See the property `_items` of type `Object[]` here.

Step 3: dump the backing `Object[]`:

```
0:007> !da 00000000021a2e10 
Name:        ConsoleWriteLine.Test[]
MethodTable: 000007feed524918
EEClass:     000007feecf77f58
Size:        40(0x28) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 1, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 000007fe91bd40c0
[0] 00000000021a2e38
```

There is an interesting finding: when dumping the array, it figured out it is actually a `Test[]`. It might be that your version of SOS is just smarter than mine and displays types correctly in `!dumpheap -stat`. My version is 4.0.30319.34209.

Step 4: dump the only object of the array

```
0:007> !do 00000000021a2e38
Name:        ConsoleWriteLine.Test
MethodTable: 000007fe91bd40c0
EEClass:     000007fe91ce23d8
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
File:        E:\...\bin\Debug\ConsoleWriteLine.exe
Fields:
None
```

This is a the test object with no fields, just as expected.

### What else could be helpful?

You have picked the second `Object[]` that was listed by `!dumpheap -mt 7fee816f150`. I don't know why you have chosen that one, but probably it's because you detected the difference in that array. You have then dumped the object in that array, which was an empty string. The second time, this list contained one more string. I could reproduce this.

To find out more about this, use `!gcroot` to see where an object is used. Since .NET objects are like pointers, two arrays can point to the same object (string), therefore use `-all` as parameter.

```
0:007> !gcroot -all 00000000021a1420
Thread 109c:
    000000000013e8c0 000007feedbca151 System.Console.ReadKey(Boolean)
        rdi:  (interior)
            ->  00000000121a1038 System.Object[]
            ->  00000000021a1420 System.String

HandleTable:
    00000000008517e8 (pinned handle)
    -> 00000000121a32e8 System.Object[]
    -> 00000000021a1420 System.String

    00000000008517f8 (pinned handle)
    -> 00000000121a1038 System.Object[]
    -> 00000000021a1420 System.String

Found 3 roots.
```

Another helpful command might be `!dso` to display objects referenced by the stack (e.g. local variables):

```
0:007> ~0s
0:000> !dso
OS Thread Id: 0x109c (0)
RSP/REG          Object           Name
000000000013E950 00000000021a2f10 System.Object
000000000013E9F0 00000000021a2e38 ConsoleWriteLine.Test
000000000013EA00 00000000021a2de8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
000000000013EA10 00000000021a2de8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
000000000013EA28 00000000021a2de8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
000000000013EA30 00000000021a2de8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
000000000013EA38 00000000021a2de8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ConsoleWriteLine.Test, ConsoleWriteLine]]
000000000013EA40 00000000021a2e38 ConsoleWriteLine.Test
000000000013EA48 00000000021a2e38 ConsoleWriteLine.Test
000000000013EA80 00000000021a2dc8 System.Object[]    (System.String[])
000000000013EBB8 00000000021a2dc8 System.Object[]    (System.String[])
000000000013ECD8 00000000021a2dc8 System.Object[]    (System.String[])
000000000013EEA8 00000000021a2dc8 System.Object[]    (System.String[])
000000000013F478 00000000021a1440 System.SharedStatics
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I am glad you do agree that the back field is an object array. I know when i look at Test[] directly I can see the one element, but as we know the list maintains an array of size 128 bytes (on .net 4.6 MS CLR on x64 on windows at least though), and when i peeked into array i see the element i added is actually in second position, the first position is occupied by something else and hence the curiosity.

Comment: @RohitSharma: From your comment I think this is a misunderstanding. Note I have 2 Object[] and as I said one of them "it is actually a Test[]". I think it is a shortcoming of SOS in that version to report it as Object[].

Answer (score 0):

The alternative way to look at this would be from the other end: decompile the code of `List<T>` (or look at it on GitHub if you wanted the .NET 5 implementation).

Using JetBrains dotPeek against 64-bit `mscorlib` I see this (with omissions for readability):

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    private T[] _items;
```

From intuition, I'd suggest that the difference between your two code samples is because that the compiler is smart: your first `Test` class has no state, and so it's essentially equivalent to a `static` class - there can never be any difference between multiple instances of the class. I'd imagine the compiler will optimise that away entirely for this reason. Once you add the field, you have state to store in the object and so the optimisation can't be applied.

As Henk Holterman pointed out in comments, the fact that your string literal might appear in an object array is incidental: a string literal in code will be interned by the compiler and will appear in data structures other than the one you've declared as an optimisation. That an `object[]` exists in memory with your string in it doesn't mean that it's being used as backing store by `List<T>`.

Regarding the default size of your list: you specify size in *items*, not bytes. Your single instance of array `ConsoleApplication1.Test[]` has a size of 32 bits, which would be a single 32-bit pointer: the one item you specified.

Comment: "there can never be any difference between multiple instances of the class" - that's not true; there's an identity difference. If you give me an array of `Test` references, I can tell you how many unique objects are referred to by the array, for example.

Comment: Good point, I hand't considered that. Would the compiler perhaps optimise to use instances of `object` instead and leave the class' methods as static, perhaps?

Comment: No, it can't. Aside from anything else, a call to `GetType()` has to return the right value.